# Is the 2013 Template Builder backwards compatible?

Tags: 2011, 2013, templating

The Template Builder will not install if there is already a Template Builder installed on the same machine. This means that for developers who need to work on both 2013 and 2011 servers, it would be useful to be able to rely on just the 2013 Template Builder on the client.

If I attempt to work this way, should I expect problems? Would this approach be supported?

Comment: I thought the Template Builder would only not install if a similar version of that Template Builder was already installed?

Comment: I had to uninstall 2011 on my system to get 2013 to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is officially supported, but there are no any problems with using 2013 Template Builder with 2011 CM, there were very few changes in Template Builder

Answer (score 1):

As per the release notes and Tridion 2013 upgrade manual, there are no dependencies with Tridion 2011 CM and Template builder 2013 tool.

The OS running template builder should be supporting the Tridion 2013 CME and should have IE 9/10.

Configuration details of internet options are available [HERE](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US&action=search&query=template%2520builder&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1377271105576&currentQuery=template%2520builder&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_0B93813448AE49CEA75F262B1B1680AC&query=&scope=&filename=ConfIEOptionsOnTBClient.xml&docid=task_0B93813448AE49CEA75F262B1B1680AC&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

If you had an earlier version of template builder client, I would expect that we would have to uninstall it before installing the new one just like content porter client and OOTB tools.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't agree with the logic in your last point. By contradiction (and to second Bart's point), you could/can run TB2009 along with TB2011 on the same system in parallel. TB2013 seems to be nearly identical to 2011 hence the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes Dominic, you are right, you have to uninstall CMS 2011's CP (i.e. 2009 SP2) to install 2013. The 2013 template builder runs with 2009 SP1, 2011 SP1 hotfix Rel 1 and of course 2013. Use 2013 template builder